# Exchange clipboard only with a virtual machine running in Parallels 14

Tags: copy-paste, parallels-desktop

I am using [Parallels Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallels_Desktop_for_Mac) 14 for Mac, running Ubuntu in the VM, with Parallels special software installed within Ubuntu.

Out of security concerns, I always turn on the Configuration setting on Security panel for `Isolate Linux from Mac`. Unfortunately, I would sometimes like to transfer some text between the host Mac and the guest VM.

Is there a way to allow only the clipboard to be exchanged with the Mac and VM but otherwise isolate it (no shared files, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

Clipboard sharing should not be affected by the "Isolate..." selection.  Check Options > More Options in the VM configuration to confirm "Share Mac clipboard" is enabled.

That being said if you want to **disable** the "Isolate..." option, the individual sharing settings are distributed in several locations.  Shut down the VM first as deselecting the "Isolate..." option immediately re-enables the sharing features while VM is running.

Here are various sharing configuration locations that I am aware of, but I suggest looking through all the sections to be sure I haven't omitted some.

> Options > Sharing
>
> Options > Applications
>
> Options > More Options
>
> Hardware > Printers
>
> Hardware > Sound & Camera
>
> Hardware > USB & Bluetooth